# Firebase :: Cannot read property of 'uid' of null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I have created a basic project in NextJS using Firebase. The user has to create an account using email and password. During the signup process, a "patient" (patient name) field, which is a string, also has to be entered which is saved in the Cloud Firestore during the sign-up process with the same uid as that of the user.

I am trying to access the "patient" field from the Cloud Firestore on another page (random.js) but it is not working as expected. How do I fix it?

P.S: I am wrapping the entire thing in an AuthProvider Context as mentioned in [this](https://youtu.be/qBGAdenirbs?t=630) tutorial.

**signUp.js:**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import firebaseClient from "../firebaseClient";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { setDoc, getFirestore, doc } from 'firebase/firestore'

export default function SignUp() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const db = getFirestore();

  firebaseClient();

  const auth = getAuth();

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    patient: "",
  });

  const handeChange = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  
  return (
    <div>
      <form type="submit" onSubmit={handleForm}>
        <input
          type="email"
          value={values.email}
          name="email"
          autoComplete="off"
          onChange={handeChange}
          placeholder="Email"
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="password"
          value={values.password}
          name="password"
          onChange={handeChange}
          autoComplete="off"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={values.patient}
          name="patient"
          onChange={handeChange}
          autoComplete="off"
          placeholder="Patient Name"
        />
        <br />
        

        <button
          type="submit"
          disabled={values.email === "" || values.password === ""}
          onClick={async () => {
            createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, values.email, values.password)
              .then( async (userCredential) => {
                const user = userCredential.user
                await setDoc(doc(db, "Users" , user.uid ), {
                    patient: values.patient
                })
                router.push("/")
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                const message = error.message;
                console.log(message);
              });
          }}
        >
          Register
        </button>
        <button
          type="submit"
          disabled={values.email === "" || values.password === ""}
          onClick={async () => {
            signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, values.email, values.password)
              .then( function (userCredential) {
                   const user = userCredential.user;
                router.push("/");
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                const message = error.message;
                console.log(message);
              });
          }}
        >
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**auth.js:**

```
import firebaseClient from './firebaseClient'
import {useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext} from 'react'
import nookies from 'nookies'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {

        firebaseClient();
        const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

        useEffect(() => {
            return (firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
                if(!user){
                    setUser(null);
                    nookies.set(undefined, "token", "", {});
                    return
                }

                const token = await user.getIdToken();
                setUser(user);
                nookies.set(undefined, "token", token, {});
            }))
        },[])

    return(<AuthContext.Provider value={{user}}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>);
}

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext)
```

**random.js:**

```
import {doc, onSnapshot, getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore'
import { useAuth } from '../auth'
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function Random (){
    const db = getFirestore();

    const {user} = getAuth();
    const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "Users", user.uid), (doc) => {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
    });

  return (
    <div>
      {
        user ? `Patient value goes here` : `No patient`
      }    
    </div>
  )    
}
```

I am getting the following error in random.js:

```
error - pages\random.js (10:51) @ random
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null
   8 | 
   9 |     const {user} = getAuth();
> 10 |     const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "Users", user.uid), (doc) => {
     |                                                   ^
  11 |         console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
  12 |     });
  13 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object returned by `getAuth()` has a property `currentUser` and not `user`. So try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const user = getAuth().currentUser;
```

Also the value of user can be `null` so you must check for that:

```
if (user) {
  // proceed
}
```

Make sure the `random.js` component is loaded after the Firebase user state has loaded. It'll be best if you use `onAuthStateChanged()` just like you are using `onIdTokenChanged()` in `auth.js`

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "Users", user.uid), (doc) => {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
    });
  }
})
```